# Unwanted code showing on a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a simple list to a `View` from a `Controller`.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            IdentityUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

            ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = manager.GetRoles(user.Id);

            // prepopulat roles for the view dropdown
            var list = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = list;
        }

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

and `View` code is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetRoles", "Roles"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        Username : @Html.TextBox("UserName")
        <input type="submit" value="Get Roles for this User" />
    </p>
    if (ViewBag.Roles != null)
    {
        <p>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
            {
                @item;
            }
        </p>
    }
}
```

Everything is running as planned but in the browser, I'm seeing this unwanted code :

`System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItemSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`

Can anyone help me remove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `@foreach` in the View code and it should be gone.

Comment: @fredrik: Yes it went away after removing `@foreach` but a new unwanted code has now appeared as: `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear for me as you are using a lot of vars instead of normal types, but this is the way:

```
    <p>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
        {
            <span>@item.Text</span>
        }
    </p>
```

Comment: You have to change PropertyHoldingText to an actual property.. we call that a placeholder

Answer (score 3):

`@item` is of type `SelectListItem`, and it does not have any nice `ToString` overload. So it inherits the default behavior from `object`, and the default behavior is to return the full type name. That's what you are getting.

While it is a bit weird to generate SelectListItem and then not use it for any kind of selection, the easiest way to fix your immediate problem is to output the text:

```
@item.Text
```

Again, make sure you are doing the right thing. Do you really need a `SelectListItem` if all you output is its text?

Comment: `SelectListItem` usually used in `DropDownListFor` to bind option values. Usage of `foreach` loop like that usually involves viewmodel class with its properties.

Comment: @Andrei Very well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `SelectListItem` to display in view outside `DropDownList`/`DropDownListFor` binding is pointless. You can simply just store `Roles` list to `ViewBag` directly:

```
ViewBag.Roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();
```

And then pass the name property with `foreach` loop inside view:

```
if (ViewBag.Roles != null)
{
    <p>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
        {
            @item.Name
        }
    </p>
}
```

If you really want to bind it into `DropDownList`/`DropDownListFor`, you can use something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name", ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>, ...)

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>, ...)
```

Comment: A much better alternative. Thank you.